# tabBar buttons are overlapping. How can I space them out better?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm having an issue with a children's app I'm making.
My tab bar items are not being spaced out properly and I'm not sure how to go about fixing it.

Here's a pic of how it looks:
[image]

If someone could give me a little direction on how I can stope my items from overlapping and space them out evenly across the screen, it would be a huge help.

Thanks :)

Comment: have you tried to resize of your tabbar images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys.

I found the answer after a little bit of digging.
You just need to add this in a your custom tab View Controller:

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {

    tabBar.itemPositioning = UITabBarItemPositioning.fill
}
```